# Render Partial View from HTML String using HttpUtility.HtmlDecode or MvcHtmlString.Create

Tags: c#, razor, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to render Partial View at the time of rendering HTML String. I am using KENDO UI Editor from where I can insert Code Snippets like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Editor()
.Tools(tools => tools
.Clear()
.Snippets(snippets => snippets
.Add("Institute List", "@Html.Action('CourseTags', 'Services')")
)
```

This will create an HTMLSTRING which can be rendered using

```
@MvcHtmlString.Create(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(HTMLSTRING))
```

But it does not execute this `@Html.Action('CourseTags', 'Services')` and it simply writes as it is.

is there anything I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: did you try to remove quotes from `"@Html.Action('CourseTags', 'Services')"`

Comment: Kendo Editor's Add is a method which takes two parameters, both are strings. So I can not remove quotes as otherwise the compiler will through an error